# xquery matches - allow non existing nodes in loop

Tags: xquery

I have a for loop and want to filter some nodes, which works fine:

```
matches($doc/abc/@def, $filterA)
matches($doc/qwert/@xyz, $filterB)
```

What also works is, when `$filterA`, `$filterB` or both are empty, to return every node. What does not work however is to **return the node if node `abc` or `qwert` do not exist**. For the default value i currently use `""` (empty string), is there another default value or another function I can use to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test whether the `abc` and `qwert` elements exist with the [`fn:exists()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-exists) function. If you want it to pass if either of those elements do not exist, you can use [`fn:not()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-not) to negate a test for `abc` and `qwert` existence:

```
fn:not(fn:exists($doc/abc) and fn:exists($doc/qwert))
```

If you want a condition to pass if either `$filterA` or `$filterB` is empty:

```
fn:not(fn:exists($filterA) and fn:exists($filterB))
```

You can consolidate the `matches()` expressions a predicate to avoid repeating `$doc` (not a huge savings, but something to think of more generally when writing XPath expressions.

```
$doc[matches(abc/@def, $filterA) and matches(qwert/@xyz, $filterB)]
```

Putting it all together:

```
let $filterA := "a"
let $filterB :="b"
let $doc := <doc><abc def="a"/><qwert xyz="b"/></doc>
return
  if (fn:not(fn:exists($doc/abc) and fn:exists($doc/qwert))
      or fn:not(fn:exists($filterA) and fn:exists($filterB)) 
      or $doc[matches(abc/@def, $filterA) and matches(qwert/@xyz, $filterB)])
  then "pass - copy nodes"
  else "fail"
```